# Const correctness with reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, reference-wrapper

In various situations I have a collection (e.g. vector) of objects that needs to be processed by a number of functions. Some of the functions need to modify the objects while others don't. The objects' classes may inherit from an abstract base class. Hence, I have something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;

    /* ... */
};

void process_1(std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<A>> const &vec);
void process_2(std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<A const>> const &vec);
```

Obviously (?) I can't pass the same vector of `std::reference_wrapper<A>`s to both `process_1` and `process_2`. Solutions I've considered so far include:

- Using a C-style cast or `reinterpret_cast` on a reference to `vec`
- Writing my own reference wrapper that has `T& get()` and `T const & get() const` instead of `T& get() const`
- Refactoring with e.g. methods that take a wrapper instead of the vector
- Having copies of the vector with and without `const`
- Not using `const` in `reference_wrapper`'s argument

None of these seems very elegant. Is there something else I could do?

Comment: I don't see the point of having a reference_wrapper which reference is const. Thats not for modifying the data in another location, is to share the ownership of the data. And thats what `std::shared_ptr` is designed for and works pretty well. I think `std::reference_wrapper` is designed for non-const references only, that explains why only a `T& get() const` overload is provided.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` also has `T* get() const`, so I don't think it would help me in this situation. I probably should have mentioned that `A` is abstract. I wanted some additional safety by using references instead of pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Range adapters.

A range adapter takes a range as input (a container is a range, as it has `begin` and `end` returning iterators), and returns a range with different properties.

You'd cast your reference wrappers to the `const` variant when you dereference the iterator.

`boost` has iterators that will do this for you (transform iterators), and tools to help write conforming iterators, but it can be done from scratch with some work.

A bit of extra work could even keep the typenames sane.

Answer (score 1):

Even lacking elegance, I would make a reference wrapper:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
class ReferenceWrapper
{
    public:
    ReferenceWrapper(T& ref)
    :   m_ref(ref)
    {}

    ReferenceWrapper(const std::reference_wrapper<T>& ref)
    :   m_ref(ref)
    {}

    const T& get() const noexcept { return m_ref.get(); }
    T& get()  noexcept { return m_ref.get(); }

    operator const T& () const  noexcept { return m_ref.get(); }
    operator T& ()  noexcept { return m_ref.get(); }

    private:
    std::reference_wrapper<T> m_ref;
};
```

It is a tiny class modeling the original requirements.